# python function look and say sequence when parameter empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to define a function with a parameter list which generates the next line of the look and say sequence. My first code worked fine for generating the numbers.However, when calling the function with an empty list I need to get a result [1] and with this code I get an 'out of range' error.

The problem is that I define `prev=line[0]`. I tried many things and none works...My first idea was to try `count,result=1,[1]` and then define `prev` within a loop (for char in line: and then another one for char in line[1:]:)

This is my first code (generates correct number sequences but is out of it when function is called with an empty list):

```py
def next_line(line):
    prev,count, res = line[0], 1, []
    for char in line[1:]:
        if char != prev:
            res += [count, prev]
            count = 1
            prev = char
        elif char == prev:
            count += 1
    res.append(count)
    res.append(prev)

    return res
print(next_line([]))
```

Tried this but does not generate the  correct number sequence!:

```py
def next_line(line):
    count,res = 1, [1] 

    for char in line:
        prev=line[0]
        if line[0]==1 and len(line)==1:
            count=1
            res=[1,1]
    for char in line[1:len(line)+1]:   
        if char != prev:
            res+=[count,prev]
            count = 1
            prev= char
        else:
            count += 1

    return res
```

At best I get '1' in the beginning of my result and last elements missing...
I am new to python and really have no other ideas.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this will help :

Check for the length of the line before doing any processing on the list, as done in the below code.

```
def next_line(line):
    if len(line) == 0:
        return []
    count,res = 1, [1] 

    for char in line:
        prev=line[0]
        if line[0]==1 and len(line)==1:
            count=1
            res=[1,1]
    for char in line[1:len(line)+1]:   
        if char != prev:
            res+=[count,prev]
            count = 1
            prev= char
        else:
            count += 1

    return res
```

Ouput:
print(next_line([]))

```
[]
```

Same goes for your first solution:

```
def next_line(line):
    if len(line) == 0:
        return []
    prev,count, res = line[0], 1, []
    for char in line[1:]:
        if char != prev:
            res += [count, prev]
            count = 1
            prev = char
        elif char == prev:
            count += 1
    res.append(count)
    res.append(prev)

    return res
print(next_line([]))
```

Ouput:

```
[]
```